# How to get file path of the file with the running-vba code

Tags: ms-access, vba, path

I want to get the folder path from the file who is running the vba-code.
For example: the vba-code is in the file C:\myfolder\file.accdb and I want the vba-code to return C:\myfolder\

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
currentproject.Path
```