# How to check which Office Application VBA code is running from?

Tags: vba, ms-office

I am currently using VBA code which was originally intended for an excel document. I could just retailor the code for use in word but I think it might be better to extend the application so that it is compatible to 'potentially' any MS Office Application. But I'm not entirely sure how to do so.

For example the excel based code fetches the document's path:

```
If libDir = "" Then libDir = ThisWorkbook.Path
```

To extend this to word I just have to replace ThisWorkbook with ActiveDocument.

But would it be possible to find out which office application is running the VBA code so that I can keep both.

```
 'IF VBA run from Word Then
     If libDir = "" Then libDir = ThisWorkbook.Path
 'ELSE VBA run from Excel then
     If libDir = "" Then libDir = ActiveDocument.path
 'End If
```

So far I can see that I can find out if word or excel is open but I cannot assume that because it is open it is running that specific module. But that is beyond my VBA knowledge.

I've also tried this [currentproject.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729752/how-to-get-file-path-of-the-file-with-the-running-vba-code) but that doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A ha, thank you for the comment. It won't be possible if that is the case, so I will stop looking for a solution to that then. Hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does sound complex trying to tool up code to suit various Office APPs. And what does this code do if it can be applied in word and excel - perhaps vbscript and then automating the object you want to work with is an option

On your specific example above, it will actually compile okay (and I haved tested in xl2003, xl2010 and word2010), so with error handling the code will run and skip the otherwise problematic areas.

```
 On Error Resume Next
    If libDir = "" Then libDir = ThisWorkbook.Path
    If libDir = "" Then libDir = ActiveDocument.Path
 On Error GoTo 0
```

Something else to consider, the Path wont exist if the file is unsaved.

Answer (score 3):

I found a need for this myself and struggled to locate any sort of conditional compilation or other means to distinguish the application.

Just now, on a hunch I discovered that the Application object in each of the office apps has .Name and .Version String properties.

So, you could do some code like so to determine which application you're running under:

```
Private Sub TestApplication()
  Select Case Application.Name
    Case "Microsoft Word"
      MsgBox "Running in Word " + Application.Version
    Case "Microsoft Excel"
        MsgBox "Running in Excel " + Application.Version
    Case "Microsoft PowerPoint"
        MsgBox "Running in PowerPoint " + Application.Version
    Case "Microsoft Visio"
        MsgBox "Running in Visio " + Application.Version
    Case "Microsoft Access"
        MsgBox "Running in Access " + Application.Version
    Case "Outlook"
        MsgBox "Running in Outlook " + Application.Version
    Case Else
       MsgBox "Unknown Application " + Application.Name + " " + Application.Version
  End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If the overall intention is to build and re-use a VBA code base that can be used in all Office applications a better way may be to use conditional compilation.  The first two cases in the TestApplication example above would then look like this:

```
Private Sub TestApplication()
    #If Word then
        MsgBox "Running in Word " + Application.Version
    #ElseIf Excel 
        MsgBox "Running in Excel " + Application.Version
    #Else
        MsgBox "Running in SomeOtherApplication " + Application.Version
    #End if    Case "Microsoft PowerPoint"
End Sub
```

(All other applications have been caught with an #Else.)

By setting conditional compilation arguments 'Word' and 'Excel' appropriate in the Properties of the VBProject that contains the re-used code it is then possible to ensure that only the code required for that implementation is compiled. e.g. the conditional compilation arguments needed for use in Word would be:

---

Word = -1 : Excel = 0

---

That is, Word = True : Excel = False, are the required settings for compilation of the code into a Word specific application.

One final general Tip:
Always use -1 for True when setting the values of the Conditional Compilation arguments. If you later decide to reverse the intent of a statement, it is then easy to change the intent by adding NOT.   This is a good idea because:

As you probably know, VBA conditional statements treat non zero values in conditional statements as being true.  e.g. this would GoTo Label Line10:
`If 5 Then GoTo LINE10`
This is OK until you try to change the intent of such a statement to NOT do something based on such a condition.  This statement will still GoTo Line10.
`If NOT 5 Then GoTo LINE10`
The NOT operator will not resolve any number other than -1 to False (that is, 0).